# Map a class which inherits a list of objects to a similar class

Tags: c#, automapper

In my project I need to map objects from the external systems to DTOs. The object I want to map is:

```
public class PriceLists : List<PriceList> { }
```

I get the idea of mapping properties within the class but having difficulty finding a solution for this case. My DTO will preferably be "identical" to this source class to make it as simple as possible for the moment:

```
public class PriceListsDTO : List<PriceListDTO> { }
```

Is there a simple solution or do I need to refactor my DTO object?

Thanks.

Edit: I have tried creating mapping for a list of Price lists without success regarding this problem.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<PriceList>, <PriceListDTO>(); });

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<IList<PriceList>, IList<PriceListDTO>>(); });
```

Edit2:

```
public class PriceList
{

    public string Agreement { get; set; }

    public Currency Currency { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<Guid> ImageKey { get; set; }

    public bool IsBid { get; set; }

    public bool IsLimitedToStock { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public class PriceListDTO
{
    public string Agreement { get; set; }

    public CurrencyViewModel Currency { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? ImageKey { get; set; }

    public bool IsBid { get; set; }

    public bool IsLimitedToStock { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

And the Currency class and DTO only contains string properties.

Comment: show you pricelist and pricelistdto class . some problem in  classes only

Comment: Updated post with the classes you asked for, Pankaj.

Comment: Always run `cfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` at the end of your initialization to verify it has all the required information

Comment: Got back to the same error as before:

`Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping
Mapping types:
PriceList -> PriceListDTO

Destination path:
PriceListsDTO[0]

Source value:
PriceList`

This occurs when I want to map the PriceLists which inherits a list of pricelists to PriceListsDTO (also inherits List<PriceListDTO>).

What to do? Same question as the original one.

Comment: The error above occurs when the following code runs:
`public PriceListsDTO Map(PriceLists sourceObject)
{
   var mappedProduct = Mapper.Map<PriceListsDTO >(sourceObject);
    return mappedProduct;
 }`

Comment: problem in  curency and currencyviewmodel . type also should be same

Comment: I do have a mapper for Currency -> CurrencyViewModel. Is that not enough?

`cfg.CreateMap<Currency, CurrencyViewModel>().ReverseMap();`

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've given, you never actually told AutoMapper to associate the DTO with the model class. If you call `Initialize` twice, the second will REMOVE any previous mappings. Try updating your configuration to do the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize( cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<PriceList, PriceListDTO>()
       .ReverseMap();
    // Not sure if this is required if you already have the model/dto map 
    cfg.CreateMap<IList<PriceList>, IList<PriceListDTO>>();
    cfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got some progress now with an error message...

AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
=============================================================
PricelistList -> PricelistListViewModel (Destination member list)

Correct me if I´m wrong:
1. I shouldn´t map the ILists again?
2. I need to ReverseMap on ALL objects I got?
3. For example: Currency should be mapped "as usual" within the

Comment: `ReverseMap` should only be used on classes that require bidirectional mapping. Since Automapper has innate ability to handle collections, I think it just requires the actual object maps.

Comment: As for the error, you will need to map child types as well, like `Currency, CurrencyViewModel` and any others not in the above code blocks.

Comment: Well, in other scenarios I need to map the other way around so I better add them.

Comment: I did add mapper for currency.

    cfg.CreateMap<Currency, CurrencyViewModel>().ReverseMap();

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PriceList
```

{

```
public string Agreement { get; set; }

public Currency Currency { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

public int Id { get; set; }

public Nullable<Guid> ImageKey { get; set; }

public bool IsBid { get; set; }

public bool IsLimitedToStock { get; set; }

public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

public int Type { get; set; }
```

}

public class PriceListDTO
{
    public string Agreement { get; set; }

```
public Currency Currency { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

public int Id { get; set; }

public Guid? ImageKey { get; set; }

public bool IsBid { get; set; }

public bool IsLimitedToStock { get; set; }

public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

public int Type { get; set; }
```

}

> after that try automapper.mapper.createmap it
>   will work for you otherwise you need to use formember method to map
>   properties of currency with currencyviewmodel one by one because
>   object are different to each other just try with it. hope it will help
>   for you . Thanks

Comment: I did map the currency -> currencyviewmodel before the pricelist.

Comment: It's doesn't matter to map earlier or not if you working with pricelist and pricelistdto and you using currency model you need to map there also i guess.